# psycopg2 across python files

Tags: python, initialization, psycopg2

I am writing a Python application (console based) that makes use of a PostgreSQL database (via psycopg2) and R (via rpy). It is a large procedure-based application and involves several steps and sometimes repeating of steps and do not always involve all steps.

I have is the following:

```
main_file.py

modules/__init__.py
modules/module1.py
modules/module2.py

functions/__init__.py
functions/function1.py
functions/function2.py
```

The init files just states import module1, module2 or function1, function2 depending which init file it is.

The content of the main_file.py looks something like this:

```
import modules
from functions import function1

class myClass():
    def my_function(self):
         scripts = [
                    # modules.module1.function, 
                    modules.module2.function, 
                   ]

         print "Welcome to the program."

         function1.connect()

         for i in scripts:
            i

         cur.close()

         print "End of program"

if __name__ == '__main__':
     myClass().my_function()
```

The reason for the loop is to comment out certain steps if I don't need them. The connect() function I'm trying to call is the psycopg2 connection. It looks like this (inside function1.py file):

```
import sys
import psycopg2

def connect():
    try:
        con = psycopg2.connect(database=dbname, user=dbuser)
        cur = con.cursor()
        db = cur.execute
    except psycopg2.DatabaseError, e:
        if con:
             con.rollback()
        print e
        sys.exit
```

In the main_file.py example I'm trying to run module2, which needs to connect to the database, using something like the following:

```
def function:
    db("SELECT * INTO new_table FROM old_table")
    con.commit()
```

How do I get Python (2.7) to recognise the global names db, cur and con? Thus connecting once-off to the database and keeping the active connection through all steps in the program?

Comment: They are all global within the module, so if you import function1, then function1.db will be db etc.

Answer (score 2):

You should add a function to the module that initialize the DB that will return the created DB objects, and then have every module that wants to use the DB call that function:

**function1.py**

```
import sys
import psycopg2

con = cur = db = None

def connect():
    global con, cur, db
    try:
        con = psycopg2.connect(database=dbname, user=dbuser)
        cur = con.cursor()
        db = cur.execute
    except psycopg2.DatabaseError, e:
        if con:
             con.rollback()
        print e
        sys.exit


def get_db():
    if not (con and cur and db):
        connect()
    return (con, cur, db)
```

**function2.py**

```
import function1

con, cur, db = function1.get_db()

def function:
    db("SELECT * INTO new_table FROM old_table")
    con.commit()
```

There's no way to make certain variables global to every single module in package. You have explicitly import them from whatever module they live in, or return them from a function call.

Comment: How do you close that cursor and connection after importing it from a different file ?